# pip install gives me this error "can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, remote-access

I have tried using `pip -m install win32api`, but I still get the error "***can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"***

Can anyone help me on this?

**Note**: I have renamed the python.exe file as python2 and python3, since I have both versions installed on my pc.

Comment: Based on how you are trying to run it, I believe you need to run it as `python -m pip install <package>`. `<package>` would be win32api in this case. You should also validate whether `win32api` is in fact the proper name that pip will find.

Comment: Renaming python.exe is not recommended

Answer (score 42):

```
python -m pip install pypiwin32
```

This should solve the issue. Note that the package name you used is not the canonical name.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your python interpreter environment variable path, you need to either `py -m pip install win32api`

or

Use `python -m pip install win32api`

In my case, `py -m pip install win32api` worked but `python -m pip install win32api` didn't

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that i had not installed pip3 so there was no directory for it so i fixed it with installing pip3

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and then checked the version of pip `

```
pip3 --version
```

and installed every package with

```
pip3 install Django=4.2.2
```

you can install any component this is just for example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message while trying to lunch the command "manage.py". I solved the problem by writing the command in python shell after entering the folder where the files django-admin.exe and django-admin.py are. Please see screen-shot attached.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In my case I fix path problem.

```
C:\Users\Chhaya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages
```

I put above path in path variable,
step1: right click on this PC, click on properties
step2:click on Advance system setting, new window will pop up
step3:click on Environment varible, you will see PATH ,edit path & put above path which in my case,
if you install in other drive find out path like `Python36\Lib\site-packages`